# Can I update to OS X 10.8 from OS X 10.7 without doing all softwares updates?

Tags: upgrade, software-update, macos

Do I have to perform all system updates to Lion before I update to Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I was able to update from 10.7.3 to 10.8 without running software updates (10.7.4) and Mountain Lion runs great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes since you are running `10.7.x` you can update straight to Mountain Lion and not have to update to the latest version of OS X Lion first. This capability to jump from any version of Lion to Mountain Lion is noted in [how to upgrade to Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/).

> ...
>
> **Step 2**:
>   **Make sure you have Lion** or the latest version of Snow Leopard ...
>
> **If you are running Lion (10.7.x), you’re ready to update to Mountain Lion. Go to Step 3.** If you are running Snow Leopard (10.6.x), update to the latest version of OS X Snow Leopard before you purchase OS X Mountain Lion from the Mac App Store. Click the Apple icon and choose Software Update to install Snow Leopard v10.6.8, the latest version.
>
> ...

Comment: Exactly. This cuts through the BS of link-bait journalism with non-advice advice such as "do all the updates", and "run a permissions repair". Time is money. And for a lot of computers out there still licensed just for Lion, it's great to save unneeded work when doing a fresh install/upgrade.